# How to configure an environment variable for a new environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using `eb create` to create a new environment. The file structure is:

```
myapp
 '- .ebextensions
      '- options.config
 '- elasticbeanstalk
      '- config.yml
```

However the environment variables are not created, which I can confirm via: Elastic Beanstalk >
Environments >
myenv
Configuration.

My `options.config` is:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
    value: elasticbeanstalk
```

My config.yaml is:

```
branch-defaults:
  feature/highscore:
    environment: myapp-dev
    group_suffix: null
  main:
    environment: null
    group_suffix: null
deploy:
  artifact: build/libs/my-app-name.zip
global:
  application_name: my app name
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: eu-central-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

What am I doing wrong? Why are the environment variables not loaded in elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are setup using [aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplicationenvironment). So it should be:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: elasticbeanstalk
```

Comment: I can't find it anymore, but I think `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:` is the default and can be omitted. After I made it work (see my answer) I tried the options.config from my question again and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know `.ebextensions` needs to be in the zip folder (thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804625/3014199). I am uploading a locally compiled jar instead of the whole folder, so it didn't go there automatically. If `my-app-name.zip` comprises both `my-app-name.jar` and `.ebextensions` it works.